# My entity list contains a copy of my player entity but not "The" player entity

Tags: c++, vector

Basically what I mean is I have my player entity and my entity list, I put my player entity into the list but now its sort of a copy of the player.

```
std::vector<Entity> entities;

Entity player(x, y);
entities.push_back(player);
```

When I move the player's coords it doesn't change the entities.at(player index) coords, and vice versa.
I would like to use the "player" instead of entities.at whenever I need it but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It's not "sort of" a copy of the player.  It _is_ a copy.  Without seeing this in the context of an actual program that uses this, it's hard to really provide a definitive answer.  This question will likely solicit opinions only, depending on how people interpret your requirements.  You could store `Player*` values in your vector, or you could use `std::reference_wrapper<Player>`, or you could ignore the `player` variable and use the vector for everything, or a whole variety of other solutions.  This smells like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200806) to me.

Comment: From what I gather, you want to use `entities` for everything, but you don't want to use `entities.at(i)` (or `entities[i]`) everywhere.  So a very simple approach that's commonly used is to just store a reference to that item while you're using it: `Entity& player = entities.at(i);` -- now when you access `player`, you are actually accessing the one stored in the vector.  If you do this, it's vital to remember that that if you add or remove items from the vector, the reference must be considered invalid and you must not use it.

Comment: Use `entities.emplace_back(x, y);`

Comment: Thank you paddy, it worked! Also I will try to write better questions in the future, I've never posted here before.